# Get data from relational table in odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

I need to get the data from relational table and check whether the given data is there. I used this code tho do that. Even though there is a search data it gives result as false.

```
user_category_id = self.env['ir.module.category'].search([('name', '=', 'Company')])
    user_new_id = self.env['res.groups'].search(
        [('category_id', '=', user_category_id.id),('name','=',"Manager")])

    query = """SELECT p.gid from res_groups_users_rel p where p.uid=%d """ % user_id.id
    self.env.cr.execute(query)

    result = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    print result
    if user_tiq_id in result:
        print "True"
    else:
        print "false"
```

Please help me to solve this error

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to do in this code ? mean what you want in output.

Comment: Do you know queries?@Ridma

Comment: But y you want to put queries. Tell me your question briefly.

Comment: solve the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

get count instead of select...

```
user_id= self.env['res.users'].search([('id','=',self.env.user.id)])
    user_category_id = self.env['ir.module.category'].search([('name', '=', 'Company')])
    user_new_id = self.env['res.groups'].search(
        [('category_id', '=', user_category_id.id),('name','=',"Manager")]).id
    query = """select COUNT(*) from res_groups_users_rel where uid=%d and gid=%d """ % (user_id.id,user_tiq_id)
    self.env.cr.execute(query)
    result = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    json_result = json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False)
    count = json_result.strip('\' \" [] ')
    str_count = str(count)
    int_count = int(str_count)
if int_count==0:
    print "fail"
else:
    print "pass"
```